# Python vs Flash

Tags: python, flash, actionscript

Can python be used as a language to develop browser based games? Like we do in flash. If yes then what frameworks are available to get my hands dirty? If no then what are the reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try to Panda3D. I have successfully used it before to create and deploy 3D game environments that run in a browser (runtime is required). Works for Mac. Linux and Windows.

Examples here: http://www.panda3d.org/gallery/

Their manual is very clear and has a bunch of examples. http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Just to be clear, by 'runtime is required', relima means that the runtime plug-in is required. I just found out about Panda3D last week and I'm pretty excited about it.

Answer (score 1):

Flash uses a separate plugin that runs within the browser in order to have better access to the resources on the system. Python can currently only be used to generate the various formats that the browser uses (HTML, SVG, JavaScript, etc.), which restricts the feature set that can be exposed using Python.

There is [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) for easily converting between Python and JavaScript, but it hasn't really been applied to games as far as I know, and graphics would still be a separate issue.

And of course, it may also be possible to generate Flash applets using Python via various libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can run IronPython code in the Silverlight plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a browser plug-in for Python. With that in mind, no in-browser games. If you used PyGame you could do network delivered game. Alternately, you could go the AJAXy route and have a Python server work with JavaScript or some other tool a browser.

If you go for a hybrid approach pretty much any AJAXy framework would work.